# Ignore query string from redirected URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I want to redirect a URL from an old site with this format:

```
http://www.domain.com/us/productos/producto.asp?id_g=1&ID=2
```

To this new format:

```
http://www.domain.com/usa/products/name/
```

How can I do this? I tried with this:

```
Redirect 301 /us/productos/producto.asp?id_g=1&ID=2  http://www.domain.com/usa/products/name/
```

But it didn't work. I think it's because the `?` and `&` symbols of the original URL. For example, this is working in other URLs without this symbols, like this:

```
Redirect 301 /caste/home/home.asp http://www.domain.com/es
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a php framework?

If you use php framework like codeigniter, setting like that is not in .htaccess, but in application/config.php

Now, You use asp (because your url), you better look first at this [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)

or you can find google with keyword asp routing or asp pretty url

Comment: I'm not using a framework. Also, I don't need pretty URL for ASP, I only need to redirect an old .asp URL to a new URL working in a WordPress. The site developed in ASP doesn't exist anymore.